# Excel cell value (text) based on 2nd cell value (number) appearing in a named range

Tags: microsoft-excel, array, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet where I want a contact name to appear in a cell `F166` if the department number `P166` appears in a named range (`PS Depts` on Sheet2).

Here is my existing formula, but it only allows for lookup of one dept.  I don't want to have to write an if statement for each of my 112 depts in the named range.  The section of the formula that applies to my dilema is marked bold italic.

```
=IF((LEFT(P166,1)="2"),$P166,(IF((LEFT(S166,5)="BU344"),"get from finance Heather",***(IF((LEFT(P166,6)="449010"),"get from Finance Angela H"***,"get from finance Shawn")))))
```

Translation :

- If the cell value starts with 2, get from Heather.
- If the cell value appears in the named range, get from Angela.
- If neither, get from Shawn.

The formula works quite well as is.  I just want to reference the new named range in order to identify which rows should name Angela H in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `COUNTIF` to check a range, e.g. this version

`=IF(LEFT(P166,1)="2",$P166,IF(LEFT(S166,5)="BU344","get from finance Heather",IF(COUNTIF(PSDepts,LEFT(P166,6)),"get from Finance Angela H","get from finance Shawn")))`